# How can I prevent content in a Xamarin Forms ScrollView becoming stuck when the orientation changes?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Say you have a Xamarin Forms ScrollView control with some content.

The content is such that; it fits entirely in the viewport when the device is in the portrait orientation however, it extends beyond the viewport when the device is in the landscape orientation.

#### The problem

When you rotate the device to landscape and scroll the content to the bottom, then rotate it back to portrait, the content does not reset and cannot be scrolled - it is now stuck half way up the page.

This seems to be a bug in Xamarin Forms as it only happens in iOS and not Android. That said, it could be a while until this is resolved. I'm looking for suggestions on how to prevent/overcome this situation in the mean time? Possibly with a custom renderer?

Here is a solution to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/afalz/ScrollViewIssue

Comment: is this fixed? Facing same issues in my ios app too

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using a shared project (the Xamarin.Forms). When programming in a IOS project, you can set the ContentSize of your ScrollView to accommodate for the changing of layout (landscape, portrait).

```
ScrollView scrollview = new ScrollView();
scrollview.ContentSize = new RectangleF(x, y, screenHeight, screenWidth);
```

You can then use the override ViewDidRotate method and change the ContentSize property.

For your example, I think you'd be best off to implement a method that gets called every time you change your screen layout, just like the ViewDidRotate method, and change the ScrollView.Content.HeightRequest to the new screensize.

I hope this helps. Good luck!